# MKMapView setRegion unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

Sometimes when I call this function with the same parameters my app crashes and sometimes it runs as it's supposed to run:

```
 -(void)reloadMapWithLocation:(CLLocation*)location distance:(int)distance{ 
    MKCoordinateRegion region= MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,distance,distance); 
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

The value of `distance` is 2000 and the location is a typical location in a Europe country. This is the error message I get when the app crash:

> -[MapPoint updateFramerate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282a58f60
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MapPoint updateFramerate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282a58f60'
>
> ---

I have no idea why this is happening. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: seems MapPoint redrawing has an issue. It has nothing to do with your distance, but it has something to do with redrawing the map, as when you setRegion, then map will get redrawn.

Comment: @GeneCode any idea where to look for so I can find a solution about this? There is nothing on the internet about [MapPoint updateFramerate]